# Is it possible to access Expandoobject properties by index?

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

It is possible to [override the TryGetIndex method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.dynamicobject.trygetindex(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-2) of a dynamic object to access the dynamic object properties by index however I am dealing with an Expandoobject (of the [System.dynamic namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic(v=vs.110).aspx)) which you can't inherit from. Is there a way around this? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ExpandoObject` is nothing but a fancy `IDictionary` which leverages the DLR.

There is no way you can access a `IDictionary<TKey,TValue>` via index. You may find `ElementAt` method of linq useful, but it is not. There is no ordering in dictionary, You can read more about [hashtable datastructure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)(Dictionary is also a hashtable).

For accessing dictionary via index you may use `OrderedDictionary`. One disadvantage is that is is not generic.

[Know more about issues when accessing elements via index from a Dictionary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24223344/c-sharp-dictionary-add-entry-with-wrong-order)

Comment: You'll find how to get a generic OrderedDictionary here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2629027/no-generic-implementation-of-ordereddictionary/6374306

Comment: An alternative to the archaic `OrderedDictionary` may in some uses be the `SortedList<TKey, TValue>` class. You can say `var fortySecondValue = mySortedList.Values[42];` and similarly for `.Keys`. However, a `System.Dynamic.ExpandoObject` does not work as a `SortedList<,>`.

Comment: Clarification: `mySortedList.Values[42]` gives the value that is 42nd with respect to the sorting by keys that the `SortedList<,>` keeps. If you want the 42nd one with respect to the order in which the members were added to the collection, `SortedList<,>` is no good. ***So my comment above could be misleading!*** One can use `List<Tuple<X, Y>>` or `List<KeyValuePair<X, Y>>` which is indexed by `int` after order of addition to the collection.